# How to html encode a string with out using HtmlEncoder in the asp.net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I cannot use the `HtmlEncoder` to encode a string in the asp.net core web API. Can I encode it without using the HtmlEncoder?

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot use the HtmlEncoder to encode a string in the asp.net core web API. Can I encode it without using the HtmlEncoder?

To convert a string into an HTML-encoded string, you can use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_).

```
var myEncodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

Besides, if you do not know how to use System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder to encode the supplied string, you can try following code snippet.

```
var myEncodedString = System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(myString);
```